# trouble accessing element with PHP dom

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to load a php file that contains mostly html code in to  DOMdocument so I can access the values of some input forms on the page. Here is the code I'm using:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = file_get_contents('./drafter.php');

$dom->load($html);  

$rw = $dom->getElementById('rW')->nodeValue;
```

here is the html of rW from the drafter.php file:

`<input type="text" id="rW" size="3" maxlength="4"value="1100"/>`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

`nodeValue` holds the internal value of a tag, like the `text` inside `<p>text</p>`.  What you want is the `value` attribute:

```
 $rw = $dom->getElementById('rW')->getAttribute("value");
```

Note that if you are expecting `drafter.php` to be executed as PHP by `file_get_contents()`, it will not be.  Its contents will just be read as a plain text file.  If you need the file executed as PHP, you can include it and trap the contents with output buffering:

```
ob_start();
include("../drafter.php");
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

// Then load it into the DOM
$dom->load($html);
```

Comment: Thanks! Also what is the best way to check that the dom is loaded correctly?

Comment: @user1258430 Just call `if (!$dom)` after `$dom->load()`. `$dom` will be FALSE if it failed to load.

Comment: hmm its still not working the $rw variable is empty. maybe im not called the file correctly. The drafter php file is one folder up from where this script is running.

Comment: @user1258430 If it is one folder up (not in the same directory as your script) use `../drafter.php`

Comment: @user1258430 See above if the output of drafter.php needs to be parsed by the PHP interpreter...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend use this php library called [simple html dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) :). It support "jquery style" selector

**Solution for your problem:**

```
$html = str_get_html('<input type="text" id="rW" size="3" maxlength="4"value="1100"/>');
$value = $html->find("#rw")->value;
```

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/